# Making a [4-Pole TRRS to 3.5mm Stereo & Mic Adapter (Male to 2x Female)] from an iphone headphone splitter jack?

Tags: audio, microphone, adapter, diy, headphones

I want an adapter that merges the microphone and earphone 3.5 mm jacks into a single 3.5 mm jack ( basically I want to build the blue adapter thingy):
[image]

I have an earphone splitter for iphones that has a 3.5mm jack as shown below:
[image]

The problem is how do I connect the  microphone pins from the 3.5mm jack? That is how do I connect the two leads marked "?" (see the following picture for what I want to achieve.)
[image]

PS: I am not sure whether the microphone jack pinout is the same as drawn. Anybody can confirm whether this is right (the microphone jack from the headset is rose-colored and the earphone jack is green-colored)?

Comment: The "mic" tip of the microphone plug _is_ the audio out. The ring is probably the DC bias for the microphone. You have some more figuring out to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no 100% sure answer to your question. Because we (and maybe you?) don't know exactly what microphone you are talking about and how it is wired.  There is more than one convention for wiring microphones to TRS 3.5mm plugs.

I would first try connecting just the tip of the mic connector to "Microphone" ring on the iPhone.  And if that doesn't work, I would connect BOTH the ring and the tip together to the "Microphone" ring on the iPhone.

Ref: http://www.epanorama.net/circuits/microphone_powering.html#soundcard

Comment: Connecting BOTH the ring and the tip together to the "Microphone" ring on the iPhone splitter did the trick for me. Thanks!